# Why does my Android app say it has no installs? It has at least a few

Tags: android

I am new to android app development, and I just released my first app on Google Play. I've had at least a few people download it for sure, including me.
However, my Google Play Console still says that it has zero downloads.
I know it's not a huge deal, but I would really like to see if people are actually using it or not.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: This question is off topic for this site. Anyway, that data on the store is not aggregated in real-time. It might lag reality by days or weeks or who knows how long. But we can only guess because it’s not documented.

Comment: Oh yeah it's updated now.